CMake Build Error with react-native-reanimated: 'mkdir: No such file or directory' (Path Length Issue)
I am trying to build my React Native application for Android, but I'm running into an issue when building react-native-reanimated with CMake. The error I get is :
Task :react-native-reanimated:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[armeabi-v7a] FAILED C/C++: ninja: error: mkdir(src/main/cpp/reanimated/CMakeFiles/reanimated.dir/C_/Users/ricar/Documents/Github/StockItUp/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/Common): No such file or directory 
I suspect this is related to a path length limitation on Windows, as the error indicates that it can't create a directory due to the path being too long.
Here's what I've tried so far :

Moved the project to the root of my drive (C:\StockItUp) to shorten the path.

Modified my babel.config.js with :


plugins: [
    // other plugins
    [
        'react-native-reanimated/plugin', 
        {
            relativeSourceLocation: true,
        },
    ],
],


But this didn't resolve the issue.
I also tried cleaning the build with : ./gradlew clean
And rebuilding with : ./gradlew assembleRelease
But the problem persists.
Environment :
React Native Version: 0.75.4 
react-native-reanimated Version: 3.16.0 
Operating System: Windows 11 
Has anyone encountered this issue before and found a solution? Is there a way to force CMake or Ninja to work with these long paths, or is there another workaround for building react-native-reanimated on Windows ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated !

"I suspect this is related to a path length limitation on Windows, as the error indicates that it can't create a directory due to the path being too long." - I don't see in the error message any signal that the path is too long. The message No such file or directory means that given file or directory doesn't exist.

Indeed, the error suggests that the file or directory does not exist, but I have confirmed that the file is present. When I move the project to a different location, I encounter a Windows-specific issue about the path being too long, particularly related to react-native-reanimated. This strongly suggests that the problem is related to Windows’ maximum path length limitation. Despite ensuring the file's existence, it seems the long path causes build issues specifically for this library.

And to add to my point, I also found this discussion, but the suggested solutions don’t work on my end.

".. but I have confirmed that the file is present." - Do you mean that a directory is present? Which one? Common or react-native-reanimated?

Both, I also tried uninstalling and changing the version of react-native-reanimated.

The version of reanimated you are using, the maintainer didn't enable the new arch feature on it which is causing this. Try downgrading your react-native-reanimated

Here is what I had to do.

Upgrade Cmake to the latest (3.31.0+) via Android Studio; Click on the "-" checkbox under SDK Tools tab.



Run $Env:CMAKE_VERSION = '3.31.0' in a powershell terminal. I have confirmed that builds unfortunately fail when using CMake version 3.31.1. :(
Run yarn react-native build-android --mode Release in the same terminal.

Thanks andrejpavlovic for the hint and solution.
Environment : React Native Version: 0.76.3
react-native-reanimated Version: 3.16.2
Operating System: Windows 11 
CMake: Upgraded to latest via Android Studio


For me, even though I've enabled the long path support from Windows' Group Policy Editor, the only thing that resolved the issue, was moving the project to a shorter path (e.g. the root C directory).
It was a long path issue ultimately!

Same here. Changing the project path solved the issue.
